# Keep values in array after submiting PHP and HTML

Tags: php, html, arrays

I'm creating a script that adds new item into catalog(array). Each time I push submit It creates new array and the older record is gone. I use number as array key so they won't dublicate and overwrite each other but still It doesn't work.
What I want is: To save every record in array.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML> 
<html>
<body> 
<?php
if(isset($_POST['Submit'])){
$catalog[$_POST['number']]=array("name" => $_POST['name'], "price" => $_POST['price'], "make" => $_POST['make']);
foreach 
( $catalog as $var ) {
    echo "\n", "<b>Name:</b> ", $var['name'], "\t\t", " // <b>Price:</b> ", $var['price'], "\t\t", " // <b>Make:</b> ", $var['make'];
}
}
?>
<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>" method="post">
  Number:<br>
  <input type="text" name="number" value="<?php
end($catalog);
$key = key($catalog);
echo $key+1;
?>"><br>
  Name:<br>
  <input type="text" name="name"><br>
  Price:<br>
  <input type="text" name="price"><br>
  Make:<br>
  <input type="text" name="make"><br><br>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit" name="Submit">
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: use session to store data

Comment: @AvinashSinha I'm new to php, can you give me an example how should it look? Thanks.

Comment: no need to use session, just post that array along with the data every time you submit, i hope you got it what i want to say :) thanks

Comment: yours data are not saved anywhere. after the end of request they simply vanish, whether you used them or not. i would recommend to use database or saving to file, to store posted data permanently..

Comment: Could you guys give me an example? :)

Comment: when form submit page refresh, then how you get previously assigned data. try with my example code hope it will be worked for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php
error_reporting(0);
session_start();
$catalog=array();
$catalog=$_SESSION['catalog'];
if(isset($_POST['Submit'])){
$catalog[$_POST['number']]=array("name" => $_POST['name'], "price" => $_POST['price'], "make" => $_POST['make']);
$_SESSION['catalog'][]=$catalog[$_POST['number']];
}
echo "<pre>"; print_r($_SESSION); echo "</pre>";
?>
<!DOCTYPE HTML> 
<html>
<body> 
<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>" method="post">
Number:<br>
<input type="text" name="number" value="<?php echo count($catalog)+1 ?>"><br>
 Name:<br>
 <input type="text" name="name"><br>
 Price:<br>
 <input type="text" name="price"><br>
 Make:<br>
 <input type="text" name="make"><br><br>
 <input type="submit" value="Submit" name="Submit">
 </form>

 </body>
 </html>
```